# diagonal of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have encountered the definition of a diagonal in a matrix in an echelon form like this.

[echelon form formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THpWT.png)

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathbf{1} & \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & \mathbf{1} & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & 0 & \mathbf{0} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbf{0} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbf{0} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The pattern of a matrix in row echelon form is in the main diagonal of the matrix, the components (number) are only 1 or 0, and below the diagonal, every component (number) is 0. To the right side of the component with the value 1 in the diagonal, any number is allowed, to the right side of the component with the value 0 in the diagonal, only 0 is allowed.

But then I encounter this example which is very confused like this.

[echelon form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLeE.png)

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{blue}{3} & 0 & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & 0 & \ast \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-4} & \ast \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Why in echelon form example, the number on the right side of 0 value in main diagonal can be a number which is difference from zero, is that conflict with the definition of echelon form?

And what is the pivot ?

Comment: The definition of (row) echelon form can vary minutely from author to author. Some require pivots (the first non-zero number in a row) to be $1$, and others do not. **Pivots don't need to be down the diagonal**; they must be strictly to the right of the pivot on the previous row (and all $0$ rows, rows without pivots, lie at the bottom). So, if you ignore that the circled pivots in your second example are not $1$s, then the matrix given is indeed in echelon form.

Comment: thank you I got it.